# How to add text on an image in Android and send it via email using JavaMail API

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I want to add some text on a picture, and then send it as the content ( not as an attachment )
via email using  JavaMail API ( [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a) ).

I don't know how to add it in the body of the email, and i'm thinking that, because i'm practically generating a new image, it must be in a specific format in order to be added to the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really have two questions here.

Question 1) how do I generate new images with some text. (in a format like jpg or png)

Question 2) how do I email an image as a message (but not just an attachment). You basically send an html email with an image attachment but use a cid source for an img tag. Plenty of examples like: http://javaeenotes.blogspot.com/2010/04/sending-html-email-with-images-with.html

Comment: Exactly. How do I generate new images with some text. (in a format like jpg or png) ? I have the image, and i have the text.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use the image APIs to generate a new image that combines the old image and the text you want to add, then send that new image in email in the normal way.